# Default methods in interface - modifier order

Tags: java, interface, default

I wonder what order is better in following examples:

**Example 1**

```
public interface Foo {
    public default int bar() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**Example 2**

```
public interface Foo {
    default public int bar() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got used to always write public modifer so I wonder what order is more clear.

Comment: So you want our _opinion_?

Comment: Yes I want to know what you think about this "virtual" problem.

Comment: For Java 8: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-19.html#jls-19-9

Answer (score 0):

Considering `public` is implicit = optional, your problem is virtually non-existent

```
public interface Foo {
    default int bar() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Of course you can add it, but it doesn't have any effect.